# PS2 game (probably budget title) where you start off on a beach, open a cave up with cannons, and then wind up fighting skeletons and worms

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I think I played this about 15-17 years ago, when I first got my own PS2. I'd proudly bought some games for what seemed like quite the bargain, only to find out that there was a good reason that they were so cheap. One of them started off on a beach. You had to solve a puzzle, I think a fairly easy one, to point some cannons (I remember there being three of them) at a cliff face and fire them to open up the cave. After that, my memories are a bit sketchier, but I think I remember having to fight skeletons and, near the end of the level, a worm that moved in and out of the cave faces. I think there was a mix of sword-fighting and gunplay, although the latter was pretty limited. If I recall correctly, the plot of the game was that you were searching for pirate treasure, but I think wound up trapped in the cave, fighting undead pirates, for the purpose of survival.

The perspective was mainly third-person over the shoulder. This being well over a decade ago, and the game not exactly thrilling me at the time, I don't really remember many other details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another one of those cases where, in the course of trying to figure out details, I found the search terms, namely `budget ps2 game pirate treasure`, which bring up multiple mentions of *[Pirates: Legend of the Black Buccaneer](https://www.giantbomb.com/pirates-legend-of-the-black-buccaneer/3030-10662/)*.

> Pirates: Legend of the Black Buccaneer is a 2006 PS2 action adventure developed by Widescreen Games and published by Valcon Games in the U.S. The game follows the adventures of Francis Blade, a shipwrecked pirate in search of the treasure of the Black Buccaneer. Early on in his adventure, he finds a magic amulet that grants him the strength and power of the Black Buccaneer himself, which he must use to fend off an assortment of rival pirates, apes, and other enemies. The game was released to largely poor reviews; Ryan Davis, in his review of the game for GameSpot, awarded the game a score of 3.9 out of 10; his criticism mainly focused on its existence as a mediocre cash-in on the Pirates of the Caribbean film series.

It looks like it was a bit further into the first level that you used the cannons to open the cave up.